# Pine script library function returns NaN values?

Tags: pine-script, trading, tradingview-api

Hi Pine Script Community,

I am trying to write library function which returns the EP, SL, TK1, TK2, TK3 price, in order draw the lines with labels. The lines are drawn properly but the text of the label is always NaN. What I have to changed in order show the price properly?

```
  enter code here
    export getEntryExitPrices() =>
        // draw lines if the last close candle is bullish 
        float entryPrice     =  close > open ? math.round(close + getEntryBuffer(),2) : math.round(open + getEntryBuffer(),2)
        float oneR           =  ta.atr(14)
        float twoR           =  math.round(ta.atr(14) * 2.0,2)
        float threeR         =  math.round(ta.atr(14) * 3.0,2)
        float takeProfit1    =  math.round(entryPrice + oneR,2) 
        float takeProfit2    =  math.round(entryPrice + twoR,2) 
        float takeProfit3    =  math.round(entryPrice + threeR,2)
        float stopLoss       =  close > open ? math.round(close - oneR,2) : math.round(open - oneR,2)
        [entryPrice,stopLoss,takeProfit1,takeProfit2,takeProfit3] 
     
    [entryPrice,stopLoss,takeProfit1,takeProfit2,takeProfit3] = getEntryExitPrices()
    
     // draw entry price line with label 
    entryPriceLine = line.new(bar_index, entryPrice, bar_index+1,  entryPrice, extend = extend.right,color=color.lime, style =  line.style_dotted, width = 2) 
    line.delete(entryPriceLine[1])
    var entryPriceLabel = label.new(x = bar_index, y = entryPrice, style = label.style_label_left, color = color.rgb(0, 0, 0, 100), textcolor = color.white, text = entryPrice)
    label.set_xy(entryPriceLabel, x = bar_index, y = (((entryPrice/100.0)*1)+entryPrice))
    // draw stop loss line with label 
    stopLossLine = line.new(bar_index, stopLoss, bar_index+1, stopLoss, extend = extend.right,color = color.red, style =  line.style_dotted, width = 2) 
    line.delete(stopLossLine[1])
    var stopLossLabel = label.new(x = bar_index, y = stopLoss, style = label.style_label_left, color = color.rgb(0, 0, 0, 100), textcolor = color.white, text = str.tostring(stopLoss))
    label.set_xy(stopLossLabel, x = bar_index, y = (((stopLoss/100.0)*1)+stopLoss))
    
    // draw take profit line 1 with label 
    takeProfit1Line = line.new(bar_index, takeProfit1, bar_index+1, takeProfit1, extend = extend.right,color = color.white, style =  line.style_dotted, width = 2) 
    line.delete(takeProfit1Line[1])
    var tk1Label = label.new(x = bar_index, y = takeProfit1, style = label.style_label_left, color = color.rgb(0, 0, 0, 100), textcolor = color.white, text = str.tostring(takeProfit1))
    label.set_xy(tk1Label, x = bar_index, y = (((takeProfit1/100.0)*1)+takeProfit1))
    
    // draw take profit line 2 with label 
    takeProfit2Line = line.new(bar_index, takeProfit2, bar_index+1, takeProfit2, extend = extend.right,color = color.white, style =  line.style_dotted, width = 2) 
    line.delete(takeProfit2Line[1])
    var tk2Label = label.new(x = bar_index, y = takeProfit2, style = label.style_label_left, color = color.rgb(0, 0, 0, 100), textcolor = color.white, text = str.tostring(takeProfit2))
    label.set_xy(tk2Label, x = bar_index, y = (((takeProfit1/100.0)*1)+takeProfit2))
    
    // draw take profit line 3 with label 
    takeProfit3Line = line.new(bar_index, takeProfit3, bar_index+1, takeProfit3, extend = extend.right,color = color.white, style =  line.style_dotted, width = 2) 
    line.delete(takeProfit3Line[1]) 
    var tk3Label = label.new(x = bar_index, y = takeProfit3, style = label.style_label_left, color = color.rgb(0, 0, 0, 100), textcolor = color.white, text = str.tostring(takeProfit3))
    label.set_xy(tk3Label, x = bar_index, y = (((takeProfit1/100.0)*1)+takeProfit3))
```

Comment: What is the definition of getEntryBuffer() ?

Comment: // getEntryBuffer function returns the entry price buffer based on the close price 
export getEntryBuffer() =>   
    if(close >=10.0 and close <= 49.99)
        0.03
    if(close >=50.0 and close <= 99.99)
        0.05
    if(close >=100.00)
        0.1
    0.0